# determine the type of object present in memory from a dump

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have a memory problem with a huge legacy application (32bits, window, c++ with GUI). Memory increase until the max limit (2G0) then the application crash.
Real Time Memory Profiler (like AQTime) can't be used (too slow, too much impact on memory consumed).
I can generate a dump for instance with the windows tool (via taskmanager).

Question: Is it possible like in dotnet (with .net Memory Profiler) to have the type of dynamically allocated objects present in memory from the generated dump?

Comment: The general wisdom here is to *not* wait until the process crashes to start looking for leaks.  Don't use .NET tools on C++ apps, they won't tell you anything.  If you can't use the debug allocator from crtdbg.h then umhd.exe is the weapon of choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have generated the debug information (pdb file), it is possible to map the memory into object to some degree.

Comment: with tools like windbg ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 may be you can also debug it in Visual Studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx